# See images one FPDF - Laravel

Tags: image, laravel, pdf, fpdf

I'm using Laravel and I install Anouar for export to PDF

It is working well, but i can't put images in my pdf files.

In what file do I have to put the image to see it, or how can Ipdf get the route to this file?

Is in public/src/images/timbreCDDOC.png

```css
$pdf::Image('images/timbreCDDOC.png',10,6,30);
```

Do I have to put the image in some special folder?

Answer (score 0):

If someone have the same problem...

```css
$pdf::Image(URL::to('src/images/timbreCDDOC.png'),10,6,30)
```